# Force Bundler to Use my Gem Source

Tags: ruby, bundler, geminabox

I am running my own gem server with [geminabox](https://github.com/geminabox/geminabox). This gem server hosts private forks of several public gems, as well as my own gems. I have a Gemfile with the sources listed like so:

```
source https://rubygems.org
source http://my/gem/server
```

When Bundler installs a bundle, I would like it to always use the version available on my gem server if it exists and satisfies the version requirements. I can't get this to work. Instead, bundler seems to pull from rubygems unless it can't find a gem with the same name there. This may be because the versions on rubygems are higher. However, bundler's documentation makes no mention of version numbers. This is how it describes source priority:

> SOURCE PRIORITY
>   When attempting to locate a gem to satisfy a gem requirement, bundler uses the following priority order:
>
> The source explicitly attached to the gem (using :path or :git)
>   For implicit gems (dependencies of explicit gems), any git or path repository otherwise declared. This results in bundler prioritizing the ActiveSupport gem from the Rails git repository over ones from rubygems.org
>   The sources specified via source, searching each source in your Gemfile from last added to first added.

Also, I know it is possible to explicitly list a source for each gem in the Gemfile. I would prefer to avoid this, since I have many of my own gems, and it is annoying to make explicit entries in the Gemfile for dependencies of dependencies (which you have to do, because bundler will not read the Gemfile of dependencies).

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Have you tried defining your custom source above rubygems?

Comment: @MusannifZahir Yep, I tried that (even though it would contradict Bundler's instructions). I also tried listing ONLY my gem server, but configuring it to retrieve gems it does not have from rubygems-- same deal, it actually retrieved gems that it DID already have from rubygems.